# jQuery Make child div bigger if other child div does not exist

Tags: jquery, width

My HTML structure looks like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"><img /></div>
    <div class="title_body">
        <div class="title">Title</div>
        <div class="body">Body text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the image is to the left and title+body to the right of the image.

What I want to do is to make the title_body div 100% width if image doesn't exist.
There is alot of .container's and I just want to make the div 100% in the container with the missing .image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (as your title suggests) jQuery is an alternative you could simply do `$('div.container:has(div.image)').addClass('has-img')` and then style `div.container.has-img` differently from `div.container`.

Comment: That's not an option cause the .container always have the same style. It's the .title_body I want to change style of.

Comment: Yes well that's what the "cascading" in CSS is for: `div.container.has-img div.title_body {style here}`.

Comment: Haha, never thought of that xD I'll try it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container:has(.title_body)').not(function() {
    return $(this).has('.image').length;
}).css('width', '100%');
```

Rather than setting the width manually via jQuery, you could instead add a class that does this.

Comment: This would make _all_ `.title_body` elements inside `.container` elements 100% width if there are 0 `.image` elements inside `.container` elements.

Comment: This removed the .title_body wrapper around all .title and .body

Answer (score 0):

if is realy this what you want, you can check the length to see if the img exist, if u have more then one, try to use [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
 if(!($(element).length)){ // if the element not exist
   // do something
 }
```

here is a [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFQk7/7/)

---

edit:

here a example using `each()`, if you have more then one:

```
$(".image").each(function(){
   if(!($(this).children().length)){ // if img not exits
       $(this).next().width("100%");
   }
});
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFQk7/10/)

---

edit: check for the div `image`:

[**Live Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/gFQk7/29/)

Comment: This didn't work either :/ I want the .title_body div to bee 100% if the .image div don't exist, not if the .image div is empty.

Comment: @Daniel Lundahl check the live demo 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    if ($(this).has('.image').length == 0) {
        $(this).children('.title_body:first').css('width', '100%');
    }
});​
```

Check the example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dymy6/4/)

Comment: Hmm, it works like you say, but I want it to be 100% if .image does NOT exist. But if I change .has to .not, it doesn't work :S